# 50% split layout with images

Tags: html, css, layout

I am trying to create a 50% split layout. With text on the left and an image on the right that bleeds off the edge of the page.

I can create a 50% layout easy, but want the text area to be no wider than 960px.

I have created this:
https://jsfiddle.net/hhwdnu3j/

But as you can see when the screen becomes smaller the background image does not cover the 50% of the page.

There must be a better way to do it so that the image covers and expands to the right side of the screen, I just cant seem to think how today!

i also want the image to be visible below the text when its on mobile devices, so maybe a img tag rather than a background image would work better?

My code is below:

```
<div class="about-top">

                    <div class="container">

                        <div class="section group">
                            <div class="col span_6_of_12">

                                <div class="content-left">
                                    <h1>Who is LCC?</h1>
                                    <h2>What can we do for your business?</h2>
                                        <hr></hr>
                                    <p><strong>LCC are a Leading National Cleaning and Support Services Provider who are passionate about our customer care and delivering a service that is real value for money.</strong></p>

                                    <p>We are committed to building strong, long term relationships with clients and also with the people who work for us. We have remained an independent contract cleaning company since our formation in 1997 with a sustainable profitable growth that is forecasted to continue.</p>

                                    <a href="#"><div class="button">work with us</div></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>

            </div>
```

CSS:

```
.container  {
    width:95%;
    max-width:960px;
    height:auto;
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
}

.about-top  {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    background-image: url('http://placehold.it/500x500');
    background-position:right center;
    background-size:50%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

.content-left   {
    width:85%;
    padding:20% 15% 20% 0px;
}

hr {
    width:40px;
    margin:15px auto 15px 0px;
}

p { 
    font-family: 'montserratlight';
    font-size:15px;
    line-height:23px;
    color:#1f2223;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    letter-spacing:0px;
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'montserratlight';
    font-size:21px;
    line-height:24px;
    color:#005dab;
    margin-bottom:4px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    letter-spacing:1px;
}

h2 {
    font-family: 'montserratlight';
    font-size:16px;
    line-height:21px;
    color:#939aaa;
    margin-bottom:6px;
    letter-spacing:0px;
}

/*  SECTIONS  */
.section {
    clear: both;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

/*  COLUMN SETUP  */
.col {
    display: block;
    float:left;
    margin: 1% 0 1% 1.6%;
}
.col:first-child { margin-left: 0; }


/*  GROUPING  */
.group:before,
.group:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
}
.group:after {
    clear:both;
}

.span_6_of_12 {
    width: 49.2%; 
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Lee

Comment: `background-position:right center;` it does cover the right 50% but it's centered in the Y axis

Comment: I know that, it needs to cover the entire height of the div too. There must be some way of having a div below the text div which covers the entire right of the page?

Comment: `background-size:50% 100%;` ?

Comment: That would work, but i dont want the background image to be stretched

Comment: Then I don't catch your point, sorry :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this by using one of the pseudo-elements `::before` or `::after`. Then applying the background that you want to that particular element.

You would only need to modify one of your CSS rules (`.about-top`) and add a new one for the pseudo-element. This is what you have right now:

```
.about-top  {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    background-image: url('http://placehold.it/500x500');
    background-position:right center;
    background-size:50%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Remove all the information related to the background and add a `position:relative` so you can position the pseudo-element later:

```
.about-top  {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    position:relative;
}
```

Now define the `::after` as an absolute-positioned element within the parent, so it occupies the right side, and the background covers it (that way the image will not be stretched, although you may lose some parts as they'll be cut out):

```
.about-top:after {
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:50%;
    width:50%;
    height:100%;
    background-image: url('http://placehold.it/500x500');
    background-position:center center;
    background-size:cover;
    z-index:-1; /* this is to send the element to the back */
}
```

Here is the code (you can also see it on this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hhwdnu3j/1/)):

```css
.container {
  width:95%;
  max-width:960px;
  height:auto;
  margin:0 auto;
  position:relative;
}

.about-top {
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  position:relative;
  /*background-image: url('http://placehold.it/500x500');
  background-position:right center;
  background-size:50% 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;*/
}

.about-top:after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:50%;
  width:50%;
  height:100%;
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/500x500');
  background-position:center center;
  background-size:cover;
  z-index:-1;
}

.content-left {
  width:85%;
  padding:20% 15% 20% 0px;
}

hr {
  width:40px;
  margin:15px auto 15px 0px;
}

p { 
  font-family: 'montserratlight';
  font-size:15px;
  line-height:23px;
  color:#1f2223;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  letter-spacing:0px;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'montserratlight';
  font-size:21px;
  line-height:24px;
  color:#005dab;
  margin-bottom:4px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  letter-spacing:1px;
}

h2 {
  font-family: 'montserratlight';
  font-size:16px;
  line-height:21px;
  color:#939aaa;
  margin-bottom:6px;
  letter-spacing:0px;
}

/*  SECTIONS  */
.section {
  clear: both;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

/*  COLUMN SETUP  */
.col {
  display: block;
  float:left;
  margin: 1% 0 1% 1.6%;
}
.col:first-child { margin-left: 0; }


/*  GROUPING  */
.group:before,
.group:after {
  content:"";
  display:table;
}
.group:after {
  clear:both;
}

.span_6_of_12 {
  width: 49.2%; 
}
```

```html
<div class="about-top">

  <div class="container">

    <div class="section group">
      <div class="col span_6_of_12">

        <div class="content-left">
          <h1>Who is LCC?</h1>
          <h2>What can we do for your business?</h2>
          <hr></hr>
        <p><strong>LCC are a Leading National Cleaning and Support Services Provider who are passionate about our customer care and delivering a service that is real value for money.</strong></p>

        <p>We are committed to building strong, long term relationships with clients and also with the people who work for us. We have remained an independent contract cleaning company since our formation in 1997 with a sustainable profitable growth that is forecasted to continue.</p>

        <a href="#"><div class="button">work with us</div></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked a treat :)